# What can I do to make my ListView stop incrementing the data every time I open it?

Tags: flutter, dart

My first Flutter project, which is a tricycle booking system, has just begun. Using the ListView widget, I wanted to display all of the active passengers that are saved in my Firebase Database. However, when I attempted to display it and place it in a List, all functions are working fine at first click. When you click the button to view the ListView a second time, all of the saved data are replicated. The list continues after my third click and grows by three. The image below illustrates what takes place when I repeatedly click on the ListView.

These are the blocks of code that are utilized for this functionality:

**CODE for Functionality**

```
retrieveOnlinePassengersInformation(List onlineNearestPassengersList) async
  {
    dList.clear();

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("passengers");
    for(int i = 0; i<onlineNearestPassengersList.length; i++)
    {
      await ref.child(onlineNearestPassengersList[i].passengerId.toString())
          .once()
          .then((dataSnapshot)
      {
        var passengerKeyInfo = dataSnapshot.snapshot.value;
        dList.add(passengerKeyInfo);
        print("passengerKey Info: " + dList.toString());
      });
    }
  }
```

**CODE for the UI**

```
body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
        {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: ()
            {
             setState(() {
               chosenPassengerId = dList[index]["id"].toString();
             });
             Navigator.pop(context, "passengerChoosed");
            },
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.grey,
              elevation: 3,
              shadowColor: Colors.green,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.account_circle_outlined,
                    size: 26.sp,
                    color: Color(0xFF777777),
                  ),
                ),
                title: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [

                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          dList[index]["first_name"] + " " + dList[index]["last_name"],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                            fontSize: 18.sp,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.verified_rounded,
                          color: Color(0xFF0CBC8B),
                          size: 22.sp,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

**Expected Result:**

[image]

**Actual Result AFTER CLICKING MANY TIMES:**

[image]

Comment: Where did you call _retrieveOnlinePassengersInformation_? Inside _initState_ or _build_?

Comment: inside the build widget @fsbelinda

Comment: Call it inside _initState_.

Comment: build rebuilds on every setstate/redraw thats why its incrementing

Comment: The data inside the list are not showing when I move it inside the initState @fsbelinda

Comment: What should I do please help @PaulGrei

Comment: Wrap _dList.add(passengerKeyInfo);_ with _setState_ and try again.

Comment: I have tried wrapping it, still it displays multiple data. @fsbelinda

Comment: Did you put it inside _initState_?

Comment: @leanTechHelp make your widget statefull and put your code inside `@override initState`.

Comment: If I put it inside the initState the data in the list are not showing.

Comment: Do you want me to upload the entire dart file? So you can check?

Comment: Yeah upload all the file.

Comment: https://github.com/Zephynity/Driver-App.git Here are the files that I am using. Homescreen.dart is where I call the function retrieveOnlinePassengersInformation @fsbelinda

Answer (score 0):

Made a demo for you how to call function once on load

```
class CustomWidgetName extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomWidgetName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomWidgetName> createState() => _CustomWidgetNameState();
}

class _CustomWidgetNameState extends State<CustomWidgetName> {
  List? dList = [];

  void myDataFunction() async {
    // do your data fetch and add to dList
    final newList = [];
    setState(() {
      dList = newList;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myDataFunction(); // Call your async function here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do I have to create a newList inside the setState?

Comment: its for ease of understanding what is where. i ddnt want to recreate whole logic. just put yours here and call setState to set dList to correct value

Comment: the best approach would be to create newlist inside function and add it once with setstate to widget.

Comment: I have followed your demo including creating a newList inside the function, however, when I tried to execute the app, the data inside list is not working. help :(

Comment: https://github.com/Zephynity/Driver-App.git these are the files that I am using regarding this function. Maybe you can consider checking it thanks

Comment: There is no dList variable defined in first file. And then you are trying to access it from second file..

Comment: Sorry I have not include it in the github but it is in the global.dart file

Comment: first define dList varaible somewhere in first file.

eg. var dList = [];
then passit to second screen trough constructor. 
And that's it

Comment: you cant setstate to global variables..

Comment: if you need globally accessible data then you should make more research about state-management and repositories. holding them in global variable is not a flutter way of handling data :)

Comment: What do you mean by passing it to the second screen through constructor, can you give a sample?

Comment: The same way you pass referenceRideRequest to constructor

Comment: which one in the select_nearest_active_driver_screen.dart?

Comment: i can't figure it out pls help

Comment: Please make an effort in learning how to pass data between widgets or just reading documentation.. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: sorry, will I implement the passing of data in homescreen.dart or select_nearest_active_driver_screen.dart?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

1. Update *SelectNearestActiveDriversScreen()* like this:

```
class SelectNearestActiveDriversScreen extends StatefulWidget
{

  DatabaseReference? referenceRideRequest;
  final List list;

  SelectNearestActiveDriversScreen({this.referenceRideRequest, required this.list});

  @override
  State<SelectNearestActiveDriversScreen> createState() => _SelectNearestActiveDriversScreenState();
}
```

2. In *homepage.dart*, declare `List dList = [];`, then change line 378 like this:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> SelectNearestActiveDriversScreen(list: dList)));
```

3. In *SelectNearestActiveDriversScreen()*, replace all `dList` with `widget.list`.
4. Finally, if you are using variables in a specific file declare them in that file(not in another file) or pass them in the constructor of the class / file / widget /screen you are calling.
   If you would rather use global variables and state managers go for packages like [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get).

Comment: when I change dList to widget.dList I get an error saying dList isnt defined for the type SelectNearestActiveDriverScreen

Comment: then when I change it from widget.dList into widget.list still the data in the list is multiplying many times.